# iteration inside another iteration?

Tags: ruby, iteration

I’m trying to output sets of numbers that look like this:

```
0,0
0,1
0,2
0,3
0,4
0,5
.
.
.
1,0
1,1
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,5
.
.
.
```

I’m having trouble iterating the second column while leaving the first column the same for ten iterations before moving from `0` to `1` in the first column.

I tried:

```
(0..9).each do |num|
  number = num
  number_plus = num
  puts "#{number}, #{number_plus}"
  number_plus = num + 1
  puts "#{number}, #{number_plus}"
end
```

which outputs this, closer but I'm still missing something related to a nested iterator:

```
0, 0
0, 1
1, 1
1, 2
2, 2
2, 3
3, 3
3, 4
4, 4
4, 5
5, 5
5, 6
6, 6
6, 7
7, 7
7, 8
8, 8
8, 9
9, 9
9, 10
```

Any guidance would be great.

Comment: `[*0..9].permutation(2).each { |a, b| puts "#{a}, #{b}" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the second iteration inside the first is one possible solution:

```
(0..9).each do |num1|
  (0..9).each do |num2|
    puts "#{num1}, #{num2}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Works and looks so simple, now that I see the example. Thanks!

Comment: @sawa How might I reverse one set of the numbers in this iteration? Doing `(9..0).each` or `(0..9).reverse.each` does not seem to be valid ways to do this?

Comment: @mann Converting to an array can work: `(0..2).to_a.reverse.each`

Comment: @mann Even easier for doing it in reverse: `9.downto(0) do |num|...`  Of course, if you want to go in regular order: `0.upto(9) do |num|...`